# installer has insufficient privileges to access "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\VMware"

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-permissions

[image]

If I try to grant extra permissions, I get "permission denied" errors.  I am not on a domain & have no IT department.  How can I solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: VMware works fine on Windows 10 - I am using it now. You need administrator credentials to install it and set up but not to just run a virtual machine.

Comment: I am assuming the the installer already elevated you to administrator.  Any decent MSI installer will provide UAC elevation for you on it's own.  It's built into MSI.  Try going to "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs" and create the VMWare folder "by hand".  Run the install again.  If it STILL doesn't work, grant EVERYONE "full control" on this VMWare folder you made and try AGAIN.. -- also.. the fact that you are using Process Monitor proves out of the gate that you are no novice.

Comment: Did you run the installer as administrator?

Comment: Was this folder created previously? Is this an update install?

Comment: Hey all, thank you for your help!  I've used the VMware workstation on the same machine, same Win10/64 without issue.  It did the UAC elevation as expected but it didn't work until I created the folder myself and gave EVERYONE full control.  Thank you for your help!

I didn't dig deeper to find the cause; at this point, all I cared about was getting it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1,Check your permissions over the installation directory.

The SYSTEM group should have Full Control privileges.

The Everyone group should have Full Control privileges.

2, Check the security software. I would advise you to temporarily disable it and check if that solves the issue.

Best Regards,